# Play - load guice module based on application mode

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, guice

I want to control the modules I am loading based on the current application mode.

So if I have the following modules: ModuleDev, ModuleProd
I want to write something like this:

```
class CostumGuiceApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
    override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
  initialBuilder
    .in(context.environment)
    .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration)
    .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }

  play.api.Play.current match{
    case Mode.Prod => initialBuilder.bindings(new ModuleProd)
    case Mode.Dev => initialBuilder.bindings(new ModuleDev)
  }
}
```

But I get an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

So I am not sure where in the life cycle of my app I should add this logic.
I was using this [article](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader) as reference

Thanks!